# Logback's AsyncAppender is losing log events, even when our rate of logging is low

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, logging, logback

We are using logback with an AsyncAppender. We've been using it this way for years, but recently we noticed that log messages are going missing. We understand that AsyncAppender doesn't guarantee that this won't happen, so fair enough, in a sense. But in our case, the rate of messages being logged is ***very low***, so the fact that log messages are going missing is very surprising.

We verified that AsyncAppender is to blame by temporarily using a synchronous FileAppender. When we did this, log messages did not go missing. Also, we tried setting `discardThreshold` to 0, and this also fixed the problem.

But these fixes are not so great for us. These logs are being written in Future-like things that are supposed to be non-blocking, and so we don't want them to ever block. If they were spewing out logging events at a furious rate, we'd be willing to live with losing log entries from time to time, but that's not what's occurring. The rate of log events is slow.

Any theories on what is going on here? And how we can fix it and keep our Futures free from blocking activities? (Leaving `discardThreshold` at 0 is not so good for us, because that allows logging events to block if necessary to make sure that all log events are written, and we don't want our Futures to ever block.)

One thought we had about this is that we do actually have a lot of DEBUG log events, but the logging level in our logback.xml is configured at the moment to INFO, so the DEBUG events are not logged.

Is it possible that the DEBUG events are somehow clogging up the AsyncAppender, even though they are configured not be logged. Until now, it has always been our theory that DEBUG events would be filtered out long before hitting the AsyncAppender queue. Is this not the case?

Or is it possible that AsyncAppender is not thread-safe?

We are using logback version 1.2.3.

Comment: You did read the documentation right? Are you losing entries of WARN or better? Where are you writing these entries to and is it keeping up? What’s the queue size for the appender?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation! But we should only be losing entries if the rate of log events coming into the queue is faster than than the rate at which the entires in the queue can be written to disk. And since the rate of logs coming into the queue is very slow, we should not be losing log entries unless either the disk is really, really slow (which it isn't) or the rate at which the queue can process entries is really, really slow. Which I suppose it could be, but I can't imagine why it would be that slow.